# Show item field when list item selected

Tags: 2016, view

I have a list called Nominations. A Nomination item has the following fields:

- Nomination ID (Title field, text)
- Award (choice field)
- Nominee (person field)
- Nominator (person field)
- Justification (long text)

In my default view I show all the fields except Justification. When an item is selected, I would like the corresponding Justification to display to the right of the list. How can I do that?

I'm working in SP2016 in a restricted environment. I can edit pages but I cannot change the page template or use SPD.The page template has only one zone.

Comment: Would you accept JS/html as an answer?

Comment: Try using connected list web parts in SharePoint.

Comment: @BeerusDev, if it can be done in one of the standard web parts, JS/HTML would be fine.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, so far as I can see, connect list web parts are not an option in my SP2016 instance. Since they don't show up on the list of web parts, does that mean that the sysadmin needs to enable them? Or does it mean that they are not a feature of SP2016?

Comment: You have to add two list (App) web parts on the page & make "Connection" between them from web part settings.